# How to prevent alpine from asking to move read messages?

Tags: email, alpine-mail

I teach 4 classes in the university and use pine as mail reader.

I have one folder for each class and for stuff like administration, computing, bureaucracy etc. and leave unresolved stuff in the inbox. After I solve the issue, I archive the message in its due folder.

Every time I quit alpine, it asks if I want to save the read messages in the `read` folder. I never do. I managed to prevent it form asking to move `read` and `sent` folders every month, but I can't find an option to disable moving read messages to `read` folder.

I believe I could do something like setting the `Read Message Folder` option as `Inbox` and then set `Auto move read messages`, but, before I try and wither get stuck in an infinite loop or risk loding stuff, I'd like to know if is there a *proper*  way to disable it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uncheck "auto move read messages".

Edited: my second suggestion is to remove the value of "Read Message Folder".

Comment: It is unchecked. Auto move means moving without asking. I want *not moving* and not asking.

Comment: Removing the value of `Read Message Folder` results in the message `No value set: using "saved messages"`.

Setting it to `Inbox` creates a new copy of each message in the inbox and marks the old ones as deleted. Still not optimal (I would need to manually expunge the messages everytime or set auto-expunge, which is a bad idea).

Comment: @EltonCarvalho remove the value in such a way that results in the message <No Value Set>.

Comment: Ok, removing the value _twice_ such that it shows `<Empty Value>` solved the issue. Thanks.